# OOPS DataBase Design help for Bug tracking application

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, database-design

lets say there are two tables TICKET and USER
table USER(username, password, roles)
Table TICKET(ticketname,users_assigned)

the problem in the TICKET table is how can I have attribute List in table TICKET. can someone guide me on how to make the TICKET table. coz I'm planning to implement the Ticket table  with List as a property using java Spring Data JPA ORM.but I don't  know how to create tables that go with it
I was thinking maybe have another table TicketUser(username,ticketname). I just want to know if there's a better way to design this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is correct.
**First Step** : add an id column to all you tables
**second step** : create a table `TicketUser (userId, ticketId)` referencing the respective foreign keys.

Or you can also let `jpa` create the table for you you just create classes in you code like

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id; // or long
  private String name, password, roles;

  @OneToMany
  private List<Ticket> ticketList;

  // constructor, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

For Ticket class

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id; // or long
   private name;

   @ManyToOne
   private User user;

   //Constructor, Getter and Setters, ...
}
```